# hapi js catbox caching

Tags: caching, server, hapi.js

I have been coding for around 6 weeks so I am new to this world.

My current task is to write cache and store the data.

I have used catbox to initiate this process, I was wondering initally how to console.log this; to check it is serving; then I was thinking about creating a server to hold the cached data.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? As for logging my cache, which tree should I be barking up.

Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: Joe, can you please give a bit more context and preferably a link to your code on GitHub?